# Windows 8 installation - can't create partition

Tags: installation, windows-8

I'm trying to install Windows 8 Pro x64 on my notebook. Previously I had the Win 8 RC installed, so the hardware should be supported.

Installation from USB starts as it should, I'm able to delete the old partition(s) and create a new one, but no matter what I try, after creating partitions the setup does not continue but shows this error instead: 
**Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition.**

It says to have a look in the log file, but the system is unbootable, so I can't look on the hdd for logfiles, and I can't find any logfiles on the install medium.

I tried to go back and install Win7 just to check, but it shows me the very same error now, so I guess the partition table is somehow messed up?

I ran GParted to recreate the partition table, which did not help.

The system has no CD drive, so I can't go back and try the XP installation CD - what else can I do to reset the partition table?

Comment: http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-installation-upgrade/75832-setup-unable-create-new-system-partition-locate-existing-system-partition-installation-error.html


http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/21583-63-windows-setup-unable-create-system-partition


try these 2 links

Answer (score 1):

It seems the installation had problems with my USB device.

I used an SD card in the internal reader, which bootet nicely but did not install (error as above).

When I used a USB stick instead, it worked.